# Magento 2.0.2 enterprise front(Customer) login not working

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, customer, login

I have magento enterprise version and getting issues with login process. When i processed for login not getting any message and also got the issue which automatically product remove from cart. i am using magento 2.0.2 enterprise version. Please improve this answer thanks.

Comment: Which domain you use? for example: `localhost`?

Comment: No i am working on staging site not localhost.

Comment: Seem that Magento 2.0.2 EE has the issue with message. You should upgrade your Magento to 2.0.11 or later version.

Comment: Okay we can understand with massage. but why something happened which product automatically remove form cart.

Comment: Do not stay on 2.0.2 version. Upgrade to the last version 2.1.5, you will see a ton of bugs resolution. If you do not override the core, it is very simple to upgrade with composer.

Comment: @KartikAsodariya you should upgrade to 2.0.x, not 2.1.x, because the 2.1.x isn't compatible with 2.0.x. You need more and more time for upgrading to 2.1.x version.

Comment: As per your concern 2.0.x not compatible with 2.1.x version so how can i upgrade my version. because getting errors with upgrade from composer.